# Load more comments with PHP and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a table of comments and a table of replies to comments and currently use AngularJS. I have a page for a user and load all the associated comments and replies on his/her profile. Since I'm just testing this on my local server for now, the sample size is very small (less than 10 rows returned). However, in order to create a scalable site, I'm wondering what I can do in terms of buttons or functions like "Load more comments" and "Load more replies".

Do I need to load all the comments of a user ALWAYS? What if the user has 3000 or even 10000 comments on his/her profile and there are more than 10000 users? Won't this take a long time for the profile page to even load? It seems like a waste to load all the comments and replies when less than 1/5 of them will even be seen in the first place. Is there anyway I can query the database to load the first 100 rows, than load the next 100 rows or something similar? What is the formal practice (and optimized for performance for this?)

As well, my general idea for "loading more comments" in Angular if I do always have to load all the comments is something like this:

```
$scope.allcomments = [some array of comments];
$scope.display = $scope.allcomments.slice(0, 5);
$scope.num = 5;

$scope.loadmore = function() {
var x = $scope.num
$scope.num += 5;
$scope.display.push($scope.allcomments.slice(x, $scope.num));
}
```

But is there no better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're going to use ngRepeat to show the results, if so:

In view, i.e.:

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in allcomments | limitTo:num">{{comment}}</div>
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.loadmore = function() {
    $scope.num += 5;
}
```